# Set 'My Computer' location on a OpenFileDialog (WindowsAPICodePack)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, openfiledialog, windows-api-code-pack

I would like to set the `InitialDirectory` property of a `WindowsAPICodePack CommonOpenFileDialog` to ***My computer*** Location, I did it using the equivalent **CLSID** or **GUID** or what the hell is that, just I would like to know if exist a more native/safe way to correctly set the ***My computer*** location, I've tried this but didn't worked:

```
.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer)
```

This is the code that I'm using:

```
Dim FolderPicker As New Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonOpenFileDialog

With FolderPicker

    .IsFolderPicker = True
    .Title = "Folder Dialog Test"
    .InitialDirectory = "::{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}" ' My Computer
    .DefaultFileName = "C:\"

End With
```

> UPDATE:

I'm on Windows 8 x64.

The other special folders such as libraries and desktop works like this:

```
.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
```

Comment: did you already try this: Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) ?

Comment: @reptildarat Yes, that specialfolder works, but the My computer specialfolder does not work, thanks for comment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Environment.GetFolderPath never returns a path for MyComputer since there isn't actually a path for it.

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The MyComputer constant always yields the empty string ("") because no
>   path is defined for the My Computer folder.

This means that your solution is the best available (and likely one that not too many people are aware of). For future interest, [here is a link](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/13591-clsid-key-guid-shortcuts-list-windows-8-a.html) to the list of available CLSIDs.